# Append customised value to physical DIV by reading and filtering complex html string

Tags: jquery, html, dom

```
var s = '<h1>heading</h1><p>para</p>';
var $s = $(s).not('h1');
alert($s);
```

This message just say me "[object Object]".
Actually I want to get HTMLString which say

```
<p>para</p>
```

And then I would like to insert that HTMLString into DIV tag.

```
$("#_Div_PreviewPane").html($s);
```

_Div_PreviewPane is DIV element.

Every suggestion will be appreciated.

**Updated**

Please let me modify my code , actually my actual code is like below.

```
var s = 'aaa<br /> '+
'<br />'+
'<div class="_Individual_Product_">'+
'<table style="width: 385px; height: 105px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">'+
 '   <tbody>'+
 '       <tr>'+
 '           <td> <img class="RotatorImage" id="CMSEditor_thumbRotator_i1_smallImage"     style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" alt="Product image" src="http://localhost:59761/Images/Products/Accommodation2.jpg" /> </td>'+
 '           <td>'+
 '           <table style="width: 285px; height: 100%;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">'+
 '               <tbody>'+
 '                   <tr>'+
 '                       <td>Field Accommodation Master 1</td>'+
 '                       <td> <select class="dynamicDropDownList"     id="ddl_FieldAccommodationMaster1">'+
 '                       <option value="1">Desc 1</option>'+
 '                       <option value="3">Desc 3</option>'+
 '                       <option value="2">Desc 2</option>'+
 '                       </select> </td>'+
 '                   </tr>'+
 '               </tbody>'+
 '           </table>'+
 '           </td>'+
 '       </tr>'+
'    </tbody>'+
'</table>'+
'</div>';
var $s = $(s).not('div._Individual_Product_');
alert($s);
alert($s.html());

$("#_Div_PreviewPane").html($s);
```

Comment: Seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cbyYg/

Comment: please see my modify code which still has error http://jsfiddle.net/myatthu1986/TCryw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `alert($s)` returns an empty string because in your code jQuery disregards non-element strings actually textNodes that have no parent element, if you change:

```
var s = 'aaa<br /> '+
```

to:

```
var s = '<p>aaa</p><br /> '+
```

Then you can use the `not` method and `text` method returns `aaa` string.

http://jsfiddle.net/XMkSk/

Comment: You are correct. I see what you mean. But it cannot be possible to change that string, because this html string come from `Telerik.RadEditor` (Rich text box) which is allowed to user to put whatever he/she want.

Comment: but I change your code a little bit according to my requirment `.remove().end().html()`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/myatthu1986/eWuna/1/  Thank you @undefined, Finally , it work because of your help

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the code into some object first (here I use a `div`), otherwise it won't convert everything to *one* jQuery object. Then remove the unwanted objects and return the content with `.html()`.

```
// Wrap and create Jquery element
var $s = $('<div>' + s + '</div>');
// Remove unwanted elements
$s.find('._Individual_Product_').remove();
// Return result
alert($s.html());
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GBWnE/)

Comment: You created div on the fly on RAM, it is also awesome. Thank @Jan

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine but to alert the text use

```
alert($s.text());
```

instead of

```
alert($s);
```

because `$s` is a jQuery `object`, if you use `console.log($s)` then you can see  `<p>para</p>`.

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5CGyb/2/).

Comment: please see my modify code which still has error http://jsfiddle.net/myatthu1986/TCryw/

Comment: What do you want to get from that srting, there is no `para` and according to your selection two `br`s should get selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<script>
var s = '<h1>heading</h1><p>para</p>';
s = $(s).not('h1');
$('#mydiv').html(s);
</script>
```

​
​

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/66WZY/1/

Comment: Sorry, copy/paste fail. I edited my original answer with the fix.

Comment: please see my modify code which still has error http://jsfiddle.net/myatthu1986/TCryw

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the code to this:

```
var s = '<h1>heading</h1><p>para</p>';
var $s = '<p>'+$(s).not('h1').html()+'</p>';
alert($s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var s = '<h1>heading</h1><p>para</p>';
var $s = $(s).not('h1');
alert($s.html());
```

.html() returns the html string

Comment: please see my modify code which still has error http://jsfiddle.net/myatthu1986/TCryw/